# Append an object on the top of clicked or hovered object using D3

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to create an interactive pie chart. When a slice is hovered it should append an object and display it exactly above the slice. The problem is with obtaining the XY co-ordinates for the rectangle.

Additionally i am using these two methods to create the hovered object. One is to have an existing object embedded at the time of creating of the pie slice, and toggling it on and off on hover. And the other is to append the object when the mouse-over event is created and removing it every time mouse-out occurs.

```
var w = 600,                        //width
h = 500,                            //height
color = d3.scale.category20c();     //builtin range of colors
var outerRadius = w / 3.2;
var innerRadius = w / 6;

data = [{"label":"Nasik", "value":20}, 
        {"label":"Delhi", "value":20}, 
        {"label":"Mumbai", "value":20},
        {"label":"Denver", "value":20},
        {"label":"Denver", "value":20},
        {"label":"Denver", "value":20},
        {"label":"Denver", "value":20},
        {"label":"Denver", "value":20},
        {"label":"Washington", "value":20},
        {"label":"Chicago", "value":20}];

var vis = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg:svg")              //create the SVG element inside the <body>
    .data([data])                   //associate our data with the document
        .attr("width", w)           
        .attr("height", h)
    .append("svg:g")                //make a group to hold our pie chart
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius + "," + outerRadius + ")")    
var arc = d3.svg.arc()              
      .innerRadius(innerRadius)
    .outerRadius(outerRadius);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()           //this will create arc data for us given a list of values
    .value(function(d) { return d.value; });    //we must tell it out to access the value of each element in our data array

var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")     //this selects all <g> elements with class slice (there aren't any yet)
    .data(pie)                          //associate the generated pie data (an array of arcs, each having startAngle, endAngle and value properties) 
    .enter()                            //this will create <g> elements for every "extra" data element that should be associated with a selection. The result is creating a <g> for every object in the data array
        .append("svg:g")                //create a group to hold each slice (we will have a <path> and a <text> element associated with each slice)
            .attr("class", "slice");    //allow us to style things in the slices (like text)

    arcs.append("svg:path")
    .attr("class", 'rohan')
            .attr("fill", function(d, i) { 

            //  return color(i); 
            return 'white';

            } ) //set the color for each slice to be chosen from the color function defined above
            .attr("d", arc);                                    //this creates the actual SVG path using the associated data (pie) with the arc drawing function

    d3.selectAll("g.slice").selectAll("path").attr("stroke-dasharray","5,5")

;

d3.selectAll("g.slice path")
.on("mouseover", function() {
        console.log('iam here');
        //alert('hello this is rohan');
        d3.select('.dot').style("stroke","steelblue").attr("x", cx -ch).attr("y", cy - ch).attr("height", ch * 2).attr("width", ch * 2);

})
.on("mouseout", function() {
        console.log('iam here');
        //alert('this is over');

})
;

d3.selectAll("svg").append("rect").attr("class", 'dot').attr("x", 150).attr("y", 200).attr("height", 100).attr("width", 200).style("fill", 'black');



    arcs.append("svg:text")                                     //add a label to each slice
            .attr("transform", function(d) {                    //set the label's origin to the center of the arc
            //we have to make sure to set these before calling arc.centroid
            d.innerRadius = innerRadius;
            d.outerRadius = outerRadius;
            return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";        //this gives us a pair of coordinates like [50, 50]
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")                          //center the text on it's origin
        .text(function(d, i) { return data[i].label; });
```

I have included a Fiddle here, 
http://jsfiddle.net/rohdz/27zCz/

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to obtain x and y coordinate of the hovered element.

```
var x = parseInt($(this).attr("x"), 10);
var y = parseInt($(this).attr("y"), 10);
```

I make a bar chart example with tooltip and use the above method to get x and y.

http://vida.io/documents/F3Ehr3qqeK28P22wn

Your pie chart slice will have different angles. Overlaying tooltip on top is going to make it look inconsistent. I recommend putting hover display at a fixed location (corner of layout or center of pie chart).

**Update**: For your particular document, you can do:

```
var x = $(this).parent().position().left;
var y = $(this).parent().position().top;
```

Comment: I think you are using Jquery '$(this)', I tried adding jquery as well and realized it returns NaN for x and y. Here is the Fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/rohdz/DBnG3/.

Comment: I update my answer for your case. It's slightly different from my example.

Comment: This is the solution i have been looking for, for a pretty long time! thank you so much...